# How to resolve Call to undefined method stdClass::save()

Tags: php, yii

I am currently working on `Yii`. I want to check that if some value is exists into database then echo something otherwise `save into database`.

I am doing:

```
    $model = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('googleid'=>$google_id));
        if($model)
        {
            echo "Good";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $model->googleid = $google_id;

                    $model->save();
        }
```

But when I am running this code then I am getting error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in E:\wamp\www\customers\protected\views\users\googlelogin.php on line 76
```

What may be the reason for this error, I am unable to figure out, please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the return of findByAttributes if no record matches? I guess this comes from implicitly creating an object on the call to `$model->googleid = $google_id`.

Comment: You should turn on php notices, so you would see something like `"Notice: Creating default object from empty value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, I was making a mistake that $model was returning a NULL value and I was insterting the value in that model, the following solution made my work :

```
$model = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('googleid'=>$google_id));
if($model)
{
    echo "Good";
}
else
{
    $model_new = new Users;
    echo $model_new->googleid = $google_id;
    $model_new->save();
}
```

Thanks for the responses